# How to change fixture values inside integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, integration-testing

I'm writing an integration test and at a certain point inside the test I would like two values for a fixture changed. How can I do this?

I tried the following:

```
@organization1.toggle!(:subscription)
@organization1.expires = Time.zone.now + 50.days
```

However, this does not seem to work. Although `puts @organization1` and `puts @organization1.expires` (see below) confirm the new values, `puts @response.body`, which shows the organization's profile, still shows the old values (making the test fail). What am I doing wrong?

Part of the test code:

```
get organization_path(@organization1)
...
@organization1.toggle!(:subscription)
@organization1.expires = Time.zone.now + 50.days

get organization_path(@organization1) # So that it reloads the screen with the new values

puts @organization1.subscription      # Has the new value
puts @organization1.expires           # Has the new value
puts @response.body                   # Still has the old values
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to save it after updating the values?

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: @organization1.save on the line after you set expires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the object after modifying the values. So change:

```
@organization1.toggle!(:subscription)
@organization1.expires = Time.zone.now + 50.days
```

To:

```
@organization1.toggle!(:subscription)
@organization1.expires = Time.zone.now + 50.days
@organization1.save
```